# In neo4j-ogm how do I retrieve one single object from the graph by an object attribute query?

Tags: neo4j-ogm

I tried to query for an object using

```
val query = new java.lang.String("MATCH (n:MicroConfig) WHERE n.nodeId = {nodeId} RETURN n LIMIT 1")
val parameters = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]()
parameters.put("nodeId", nodeId)
val all = session.queryForObject(new MicroConfig().getClass, query, parameters)
```

However it returns a GraphModel, not the MicroConfig class I wanted back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Checking Assumptions:

First, is `MicroConfig` a class that is managed by the OGM (i.e. Does it appear in a package that is supplied to the `SessionFactory` constructor)?

Second, is your query wanting to check `ID(n) = {nodeId}`? This will check that the Neo4j internal ID is matches the supplied `nodeId` argument. Otherwise this must be an actual property on the class `MicroConfig`.

#### Potential solutions:

With the current API you could do this in two ways:

1. Use a `Filter` and return only one item from the `Collection`.
   You can do something like:

   ```
   val microConfig = session.loadAll(classOf[MicroConfig], new Filter("nodeId", nodeId)).lift(0)
   ```
2. Double check the Scala `class` going in to the `session.queryForObject`.  Keep your existing query but use `classOf[MicroConfig]` instead of `new MicroConfig().getClass`.